# Learning SQL practice

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and came across the sql-practice website. And stuck with this question:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,'patient' AS role FROM patients 
union ALL
select first_name, last_name,'doctor' FROM doctors
```

What I'm trying to find is where the 'patient' comes from; there is no patient row in the patients table.

i've try to write:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,'patient_id' AS role FROM patients 
union ALL
select first_name, last_name,'doctor_id' FROM doctors
```

but it returned an unexpected output.

Comment: `'patient'` is a string literal, a value. By adding these to the select list, you'll see if each person returned is a patient or doctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no column called `role`, but you are inventing it as part of the query. Because you are selecting from a patient table and a doctors table, you would end up with a list of names and no understanding of where they came from.

By adding a hard-coded value, and calling it `role`, your list will make it clear which folks are patients and which are doctors.

When using a `UNION`, it's best to make sure the exact same column names are used, so use `AS role` in both queries, like this:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    'patient' AS role
FROM
    patients 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    'doctor' AS role
FROM
    doctors
```